# Angular 8 / Material : subform not showing errors

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, angular-validation

I created a form with a conditional subform this way:

In the parent form:

```
<form [formGroup]="layerFormGroup" (submit)="submit()" #f="ngForm">
  ...
  <div *ngIf="layerFormGroup.value.mode == 'features'">
    <app-edit-layer-features formControlName="modeFormGroup"></app-edit-layer-features>
  </div>
```

with the TS:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.layerFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    ...
    modeFormGroup: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}

public submit() {

  if (!this.layerFormGroup.valid) {
    return;
  }
```

Then the child form is:

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="modeFormGroup">
<mat-horizontal-stepper>

    <mat-step label="Collection" [stepControl]="modeFormGroup">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Collection</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="collectionCtrl">
                <mat-option value="col1">col1</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="col2">col2</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Rendered geometry" [stepControl]="modeFormGroup">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Rendered geometry</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="geometryCtrl">
                <mat-option value="geoshape">a geopoint</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="geopoint">a geoshape</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

and finally the child view:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-edit-layer-features',
templateUrl: './edit-layer-features.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit-layer-features.component.scss'],
providers: [
  {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => EditLayerFeaturesComponent),
    multi: true
  },
  {
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => EditLayerFeaturesComponent),
    multi: true
  }
]
})
// ControlValueAccessor: see https://christianlydemann.com/form-validation-with-controlvalueaccessor/
export class EditLayerFeaturesComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {

  public modeFormGroup: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    collectionCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
    geometryCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
  });

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public onTouched: () => void = () => { };

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj) {
      this.modeFormGroup.patchValue(obj, { emitEvent: false });
      this.onTouched();
    }
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.modeFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    isDisabled ? this.modeFormGroup.disable() : this.modeFormGroup.enable();
  }
  validate(control: AbstractControl): import('@angular/forms').ValidationErrors {
    return this.modeFormGroup.valid ? null : { invalidForm: { valid: false, message: 'Features fields are invalid' } };
  }
  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
    this.modeFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }
}
```

The issue is the following: when I call the submit() method in the parent form, then the mat-error tags are added in the parent form but not in the child form, i.a. validation errors are shown in the parent form but not in the child one.

After some tests, I found out that calling

```
this.modeFormGroup.markAllAsTouched()
```

in the child form will indeed show the child errors. Anyway I this should be called from the parent `submit()` method and I can't find how to do it (`this.layerFormGroup.get('modeFormGroup').valid` doesn't do the job).

I feel like I am missing something related to material, any clue?

Thx.

Edit 1 : I created a stackblitz where you can see the problem : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eldyyc . If you only choose the mode = `Features` and you click on `save layer` then only the `name` is displayed as an error, not the subform fields

Comment: As I can see, you already have a reference to `modeFormGroup` in the parent component since you are already passing it to the child component. I think you can call the `markAllAsTouched()` method from there without a problem.

Comment: It is not working. A strange thing is that `modeFormGroup` is a FormControl where in the child form it is the FormGroup. So this is not the same instance, so the parent has no control over the child.

Comment: Then why don't you create a FormGroup with nested FormGroup in the parent component. That way `modeFormGroup` will actually be a form group instead of form control

Comment: Even if the sub-form is a GroupForm, it is still not the same instance. I feel like angular manages 2 different instances, and values are transferred using the `registerOnChange` method

Comment: I created this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-vwuyaq) but it is with Angular 7. `markAllAsTouched` is supported since Angular 8.

Comment: Thank you @Superiom I think in my case it can't work this way, because I don't create the sub-form in the parent component. Instead, I delegate it to the child by implementing `ControlValueAccessor`. I guess that the problems I have are caused by the way that angular / material handle such implementation.

Comment: I edited my question to add a stackblitz link to see the error in action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the communication between the components and the reference to the original parent form group. You see, you create the form group in the parent component with `modeFormGroup` as a nested form group without any controls. Then you don't pass the reference to the `layerFormGroup` to the child component.

On the other hand, in the child component you create local property `modeFormGroup`. This `modeFormGroup` is not the same as the `modeFormGroup` in `layerFormGroup`.

```js
this.layerFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      mode: ['', Validators.required],
      id: [''],
      modeFormGroup: this.formBuilder.group({})  //not the same as in the child component
});
```

Note that `modeFormGroup` is an empty form group, without any controls. Now, in the child component, you create the child form group as:

```js
// totally different form group
public modeFormGroup: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    collectionCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
    geometryCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

What you need to do is, once the child component is initialized, within the `ngOnInit()` function to emit the created form group with `EventEmitter`, and assign the form group to the `modeFormGroup` control in the parent form group.

I edited your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qh8tpz)

Comment: Thank you, it works. However this no totally perfect; by getting the child formgroup manually from the parent, then there is no need to declare the subform as a ControlValueAccessor as its goal is to manage the binding to the parent form. For example, as you did, when I load values into the form I also have to manually load the values of the subforms (whereas with ControlValueAccessor I hadn't to).